# Fix renaming of pages (keep links intact) after cut and insert

Tags: microsoft-onenote, hyperlink, microsoft-onenote-2013

My problem can be reproduced with 2 pages in one section. Of course my situation is more complex, and what I do below was done in the intention to restructure a section that had 47 pages.

The first page is a kind of overview page (`Overview`) that links to the second page (`Content 1`). When you rename the second page (e.g. to `Content A`), the link remains intact.

Now, cut the second page (`Content A`) with the intention to move it somewhere else. Then, e.g. find out that you selected the wrong page and insert it back in the same position. Go to the overview page and click the link. It still works.

Then, rename the page (`Content I`), go to the overview page and click the link. It will bring you to a deleted version of (`Content A`) instead of the correct page.

I did this with 47 pages. Is there a quick way of fixing the linking between the pages so that renaming does not result in a broken link?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You can right-click on the link, choose edit hyperlink, then click on the correct page.